# Getting symfony query and result cache to work against oracle 11g

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, memcached, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to get the memcache query/result cache working with Oracle. It works flawlessly against mysql (verified with memcached console: ./memcached -u nobody -m 40 -vv). Here's what's in web/index.php:

```
$servers = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 11211,
    'persistent' => false
);

$cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache(array(
    'servers' => $servers,
    'compression' => false,
    'prefix' => 'qc-')
);
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 3600);
```

This works as supposed against MySQL but fails with following message at the first location where i use ->useResultCache(true):

> Result Cache driver not initialized.

Does anyone have clue about what's happening and/or if there's additional configuration needed to get it working with Oracle DB backend?

Thanks.

Comment: If you modify `Doctrine/Connection.php` by using var_dump() on `Doctrine::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE`, `$this->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE)` and `$this->attributes` on line 1320, what is printed?

Comment: $this->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE) is NULL, Doctrine::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE is "150". i couldn't get the var_dump on $this->attributes as the var_dump goes nuts every time i try to use it on any symfony objects. i did found a loop that iterates through those values on line 491 and added echo statements there, so key value pairs printed out were:
16 => oracle
8 => 0
3 => 2

Does that help? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I just noticed I asked you to check the `Doctrine/Connection.php` class, and in your code, your setting the attribute of a `Manager`. So, I guess the problem is the manager settings are not passed to the connection, which is the normal behavior. If you can't find why, you can try setting the connection's attributes directly. See [this § about levels of configuration](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/configuration#levels-of-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try to set those manager attributes inside your YOUR_APPConfiguration class like explained here : http://www.funstaff.ch/2009/03/19/le-cache-de-resultat-avec-doctrine

```
class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
  {
    $servers = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 11211,
        'persistent' => false
    );

    $cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache(array(
        'servers' => $servers,
        'compression' => false,
        'prefix' => 'qc-')
    );
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 3600);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 3600);
  }
}
```